# How can we limit the end date selection to +90 days from now on core Date Range widget?

Tags: entities, 9

We're using Drupal 9's core Date Range module and need to limit the end date selection to no more than 90 days from today.

I've searched far and wide and have not come up with a workable solution. Seems like it should be simple but I'm stumped.

[image]

Comment: This should be closed because there is no focussed question here. But as a general hint, you should create a custom constraint: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/entity-validation-api/defining-constraints-validations-on-entities-andor-fields

Comment: I read the question as, "How to limit the date selection **in the UI widget** to +90 days?"  In such a case, I don't think a constraint helps because the constraint is applied when the form is submitted, so the widget will still allow selecting an invalid date (which the constraint will block after submission).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with hook_form_alter():

```
 $limit = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+" . 90 . " day"));
 $form['field_job_posting_date']['widget'][0]['end_value']['#attributes']['max'] = $limit;
```